# angular print printing a second blank page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to print an content of my html page.

I'm using this [angularPrint](https://github.com/samwiseduzer/angularPrint) but the problem im having is that in the page preview i'm getting to pages. the first one has content and the second one is a blank page. I'm trying to get rid of the blank page.

this is my html

```
    <div id="invoice" print-section="" print-only="">
  <div class="invoice">
    <div class="invoice-company">{{user.store.name}}</div>
    <div class="invoice-header">
      <div class="invoice-from"><small>from</small>
        <address class="m-t-5 m-b-5"><strong>{{user.store.name}}.</strong><br/>{{user.store.address.street}}<br/>{{user.store.address.city}}, {{user.store.address.zipCode}}<br/>Phone: {{user.store.phone}}</address>
      </div>
      <div class="invoice-date">
        <div class="date m-t-5">{{saleDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</div>
        <div class="invoice-detail"># {{saleId}}<br/>Cashier {{user.firstName}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="invoice-content">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-invoice">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Item</th>
              <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in sale.items">
              <td>{{item.name}} {{item.size}}</td>
              <td>{{item.price | currency}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="discount in sale.discounts">
              <td>{{discount.name}}</td>
              <td>- {{discount.price | currency}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="invoice-price">
        <div class="invoice-price-left">
          <div class="invoice-price-row">
            <div class="sub-price"><small>SUBTOTAL</small>{{sale.subtotal | currency}}</div>
            <div class="sub-price"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
            <div class="sub-price"><small>TAX</small>{{sale.tax}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="invoice-price-right"><small>TOTAL</small>{{sale.total | currency}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="invoice-footer text-muted">
      <p class="text-center m-b-5">Thank you for coming.<br/>We hope you'll visit again.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the directive that trigger the print action

```
<button type="button" print-btn="">Print</button>
```

I want a solution it doesn't matter if I have to use plain javascript/jQuery or no directive at all. I just to be able to populate an invoice and print it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you could add

```
#invoice:last-child {
    page-break-after: auto;
}
```

to remove the last page

*Note: Not supported in IE*

Comment: try this `@media print { body #invoice { width: 90%; max-width: 1048px; } }`

Comment: I tried: @media print {
    #invoice:last-child {
        page-break-after: always !important;
    }
}